# This loop does not end when it meets the condition

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm trying to write a program to get a character and then check and print if it is in uppercase or lowercase. Then I want it to keep looping until the user enters a "0" which should produce a message. What doesn't work is the while condition at the bottom, the condition never seems to be met.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int ch,nope;    // Int ch and nope variable used to terminate program
    do       // start 'do' loop to keep looping until terminate number is entered
    {
        printf("Enter a character : ");             // asks for user input as a character
        scanf("%c",&ch);                            // stores character entered in variable 'ch'
        if(ch>=97&&ch<=122) {                       // starts if statement using isupper (in built function to check case)
            printf("is lower case\n");
        } else {
            printf("is upper case\n");
        }
    }
    while(ch!=0);                                     // sets condition to break loop ... or in this case print message
    printf("im ending now \n\n\n\n\n",nope);     // shows that you get the terminate line

}
```

Comment: `ch!=0` is wrong, should be `ch!='0'`

Comment: The magic numbers 97 and 122 are a bad idea. Use `'a'` and `'z'`, or just call `islower()`, declared in `<ctype.h>`. Also, the code will report "is upper case" for digits and punctuation characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `while(ch!=48);` as 48 is the decimal number for the char '0'.
As Maroun Maroun mentioned, while(ch!='0'); is more comprehensible.

If you don't want the uppercase message to get displayed when the user enters a '0', you could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char ch,nope;    // Int ch and nope variable used to terminate program
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter a character : ");             // asks for user input as a character
        scanf("%c",&ch);                            // stores character entered in variable 'ch'
        if(ch==48) {
            break;
        }
        if(ch>=97&&ch<=122) {                      // starts if statement using isupper (in built function to check case)
            printf("is lower case\n");
        } else {
            printf("is upper case\n");
        }

    }
    printf("im ending now \n\n\n\n\n",nope);     // shows that you get the terminate line

}
```

Comment: That works! Brilliant . But for some reason it prints the uppercase statement as well as printing the terminate statement.

Comment: That's because the condition you're checking happens on the end of the while loop. First the code gets executed, then the condition is checked.

Comment: I added the complete code, so it will exit immediately when the user enters a zero and will not check for the casing.